# angularJS : make ngClass related with $localstorage

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm try to implement an angularJS and I would like to make a dynamic class related with my $localstorage.

I have a script define the $localstorage like this :

```
$localstorage.set('nf-fajr', true); 
$localstorage.set('nf-dhuhr', false);   
$localstorage.set('nf-asr', false); 
$localstorage.set('nf-maghrib', false); 
$localstorage.set('nf-isha', false);
```

and I want these variables related with this elements

```
<span ng-class="{icon ion-ios7-bell : nfFajr}" on-tap="toggleNotification('fajr')"></span>
```

for example, if I change `nf-fajr` to **false**, the `<span>` should be changed to another class.

any suggestion?

Regards.

Comment: Do you mean you want to watch the localstorage change in angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest storage all this style into the same storage so that you can use only one watch to inspect style storage change:

```
$localstorage.set('style', JSON.stringify({'nf-asr': false, 'nf-fajr':true, 'nf-dhuhr': false})
```

Then you can use $watch to inspect this change:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    $localstorage.get('style'); //Maybe you need to parse json string to object.
}, function(newStyle){
    //here to handle change.
}, true);
```

[Here is jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tyler_z_yang/ppxundk8/4/)

Hope this work for you. : )